# SELECT con rango de fecha

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una base de datos con registros que tienen vigencia de 12 meses;
entonces necesito realizar una consulta para listar todo lo que tenga menos de 12 meses de antigüedad.

Estoy usando:

```
SELECT COUNT(columna) FROM tabla WHERE ....
```

Ya que necesito listar cantidad de registros con menos de 1 año de antigüedad.

Comment: menos de 12 meses de antiguedad con respecto a que fecha? a la del dia de hoy?, auna fecha aleatoria?, por cierto que gestor de bases de datos usas?

Comment: Correcto a la fecha de hoy, estoy usando Sql server managment studio  y para que acceda el usuario hice un programa en C# y la verdad no se me ocurre como implementar eso en alguna de las 2

Comment: es decir usas SQL Server, por otro lado tu columna donde almacenas la fecha, que tipo es: `DATE`, `DATETIME`?

Comment: where campo between hoy and hoy-1 año? eso es lo que estas preguntando?

Comment: Aqui te dejo una pagina con funciones y fechas utiles de SQL Server: https://bloginspanish.wordpress.com/2014/01/04/funciones-de-fecha-utiles-en-sql-server/comment-page-1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puede utilizar esto en el where con el comando **DATEADD** para aumentar o disminuir la fecha, seria.

```
Select COUNT(columna) FROM tabla WHERE "FECHA" BETWEEN (DATEADD(MONTH, -12, 
"FECHAACTUAL")) AND "FECHAACTUAL"

Select COUNT(columna) FROM tabla WHERE "FECHA" BETWEEN (DATEADD(year, -1, 
"FECHAACTUAL")) AND "FECHAACTUAL"
```

En el cual puedes utilizar aumentar o disminuir fechas(días, meses y años).

Saludos.